# How to regenerate gradlew and gradlew.bat

Tags: android, gradlew

I delete some flavor from my project. I delete them from hard disk, and from the `build.gradle` file. It compiles nicely within the android studio, and disappear from the Build Flavorsetting and from the build types.

But when running `gradlew` from command line, it still ask for the delete flavor and fail

So, how can I regenerate `gradlew` files in order to be able to use it without the delete flavor?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the ".gradle" directory in the project-root that contains compiled gradle files?

Comment: I delete .gradle, gradle and .idea and recompile. Now it throws another error but different from trying to recompile deleted flavours. So, I;ll try to find out why it throws this new errors when compiling directly from studio does not. But this is another issue I think.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.0` command and change which version you want to have. Or you can add the following lines into your `build.gradle` file.

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: this resolved where the gradlew was created on windows machine..checked in...downloaded to linux (or mac) machine...and the gradlew didn't have unix line endings.  I just regenerated it with this call.  note, I am NOT talking about "gradlew.bat".